# "Undefined reference" when linking C code in Linux

Tags: gcc, linker, undefined-reference, cc

I have a code library (written entirely in C) that I typically compile under Windows, into a `.DLL`.

I want to compile it under Linux so I can distribute it. I don't care if I distribute it as a `.a`, a `.so`, or a bunch of `.o` files.

All of the individual `.c` files compile successfully. But when I try to compile a test executable that includes all the `.o` files, I get a bunch of undefined reference errors.

All of the `.o` files are on the command line as full paths, and I don't get any errors about missing files.

`cc testctd.c -o testctd.out -lm -lc $LIBRARY-PATH/*.o`

I also have undefined references to `_open`, `_write`, etc.

Comment: Can you paste the complete compile command line and the error message?

Comment: What command are you using to link things into an executable? And what are the undefined references too, other than _open, _write etc?

Comment: Edited to show the command line. The error message is "Undefined reference to ..." where ... is _open, _write, and a bunch of the routines from my library that are used in the program.

Comment: Can we see the complete, unedited linker output, please?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given enough information for a complete answer, but I think I know *one* of your problems:  The functions `open`, `read`, `write`, `close`, etc. have underscores in front of their names on Windows, but they do *not* on Linux (or any other Unix for that matter).  The compiler should have warned you about that when you compiled the `.c` files -- if it didn't, turn on warnings!  Anyway, you're going to have to remove all those underscores.  I would recommend a header file that does something like the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define open(p, f, m) _open(p, f, m)
#define read(f, b, n) _read(f, b, n)
#define write(f, b, n) _write(f, b, n)
#define close(f) _close(f)
/* etc */
#endif
```

and then use only the no-underscore names in your actual code.

Also, `-l` options (such as `-lm`) must be placed *after* all object files.  It is unnecessary to specify `-lc` (and it may cause problems, under circumstances which are too arcane to go into here).

Answer (score 2):

You have the -l options in the wrong place

> -llibrary
>
> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance> and is not recommended.)
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus,
>
> foo.o -lz bar.o
>
> searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then uses  this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.